# Get a VBS file to scan computer for a file

Tags: vbscript

This is my first post, but I have been programming for a long time now

I just want to ask a quick question and the title explains it all. I want my VBS to run a file, but I dont want it to search just for a specific directory, I want it to just find the file if you know what I mean, because if I gave the script to anyone else, this file could be ANYWHERE on their computer.

This is the current couple of important lines that I am using for running files:

```
set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
```

and

```
wshshell.run <program directory here>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function like this one searching for shortcuts.

```
Sub GenerateHotkeyInFolder(Fldr) 
    on error resume next 
    set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FldrItems=Fldr.Items
    For Each oFile in FldrItems
        With oFile
        If .IsFileSystem = true And .IsLink = true And .Type <> "Shortcut to MS-DOS Program" then
            set lnk = WshShell.CreateShortcut(oFile.Path) 
            If lnk.hotkey <> "" then 
                Set fsop = fso.GetFile(.Path)
                LnkName = "<b>" & fso.GetBaseName(fso.GetFile(.Path)) & "</b><br>" & fsop.ParentFolder.path & "\" & fso.GetBaseName(fso.GetFile(.Path)) & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(fso.GetFile(.Path))
                TableVar = TableVar & "<tr><td><b>" & lnk.hotkey & "</b></td><td><a class=TblURL  onmouseover='MakeRed()' onmouseout='MakeBlack()' onclick='FindShortcut(" & Chr(34) & lnk.fullname & Chr(34) & ")'>" & lnkname & "</a>" & "</td><td><a class=TblURL  onmouseover='MakeRed()' onmouseout='MakeBlack()' onclick='FindShortcut(" & Chr(34) & lnk.targetpath & Chr(34) & ")'>" & lnk.targetpath & "</a></td></tr>" & vbcrlf
            End If 
        ElseIf .IsFileSystem = true And .IsFolder = true then
            GenerateHotkeyInFolder(.GetFolder)
        End If          
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner programmer and don't really understand most of that means or does. Are you able to explain a bit of what every little bit of code does, so I can learn? Thanks!